# First time using functions, and not sure why my program isn't doing anything?

Tags: c++

My program is supposed to calculate the sum of all the squares of numbers up until the users input. For example if the user inputs 2, the function will perform : (1^2 + 2^2) However my program refuses to do anything when run. (Not sure if this is a function problem, or with the main body.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int sumofsquares (int num)

{
int i;
int answer;

for(int i=0; i <= num; i++){
answer = (num * num)+ num;
}
return (answer);

}


int main(){
int num;
cout<< "Enter a number" <<endl;
cin >> num;
while( num != -1){
sumofsquares(num);
}
cout<< "The sum of squares is "<< num <<endl;


return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign the return value of the function to something - in your case, since you're printing `num`, to `num` itself:

```
num = sumofsquares(num);
```

After you do this, your function will enter an infinite loop if `num` isn't `-1` because you never modify it. You probably meant:

```
while( num != -1){
   cin << num;
}
sumofsquares(num);
```

After this, you're left with the bugs in the function:

```
int answer;
for(int i=0; i <= num; i++){
answer = (num * num)+ num;
}
```

should be

```
int answer = 0;
for(int i=0; i <= num; i++){
answer += i*i;
}
```

[**The real problem however** is that you're missing basic C++/logic knowledge, to which the only solution is to learn from a good book.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Appreciate the help! I'm just a first year student so this stuff is pretty foreign to me.

Answer (score 2):

In `sumofsquares` change:

```
int answer;
```

to:

```
int answer = 0;
```

so that `answer` is properly initialised.

Also you need to change:

```
answer = (num * num)+ num;
```

to:

```
answer = (i * i) + answer;
```

otherwise you're squaring the wrong variable and adding it to the wrong accumulator.

See the other answers below for info on fixing the problems in `main`.

Also you should learn to format your code properly - that will make it much easier to read, debug and maintain, both for others and for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You just called the function without getting the return value of it.

First option:

```
cout<< "The sum of squares is "<< sumofsquares(num) <<endl;
```

Second option:

```
num=sumofsquares(num);
cout<< "The sum of squares is "<< num <<endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
int answer = 0;
...
...
...
answer = answer + (i * i);
```

Comment: That alone doesn't fix anything.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is stuck in the `while` loop, since the termination condition `num != -1` will never change. This is because the variable `num` is passed to `sumofsquares` by value, rather than by reference. Thus changing the `num` variable in `sumofsquares` will have no effect on the `num` variable in `main`. Replace your `while` statement with:

```
while (num != -1) {
    num = sumofsquares(num);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

//Prototype
int sumofsquares(int num);

void main()
{
    int num;  
    int answer;

    cout >> "Enter a number.\n";
    //Get number input
    cin << num;
    //Call your workhorse function
    answer = sumofsquares(num);
    //Double check my >> directions :P  Format may be wrong here 
    cout >> "Sum of squares for " >> num >> "is " >> answer >> "\n";
}

int sumofsquares(num)
{
    int answer;
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        answer = answer + ( i * i );
    }

    return answer;
}
```

Comment: Appreciate it! Nice to be able to see exactly where I was going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you should note that you used cin to initialize num, so amongst the issues pointed out by others, keep in mind that you should use cin to initialize a string/char, then change that to an integer:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int sumofsquares (int num){
  //should have initialized answer to zero
  int i, answer = 0;
  //this for loop now accomplishes what you want
  for(i=0; i <= num; i++){
    answer = (i^2) + answer;
  }
  return (answer);
}


int main(){
  int num, ans;
  string input;
  cout<< "Enter a number" <<endl;
  cin >> input;
  num = atoi(input.c_str());
  //this was an infinite loop, here's how to check what you wanted to check.
  if (num >= 0){
    ans = sumofsquares(num);
    cout << "The sum of squares is: " << ans << endl;
    return 0;
  }
  else { 
    cout<< "Error: The number you have called this function with is invalid." << endl;
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Something along these lines...